# Как заполнить массив структур в C#?

Tags: c#

До этого писал на D, и немного сложновато понять как в C# сделать тоже самое.

Суть. Мне нужен массив структур. Сама структура - это описание полей в БД. Т.е. я хочу все данные из БД записать в массив структур. Как это правильно сделать?

```
   struct UserData
    {
        public int id;
        public string guid;
        public string name;
        public byte[] userblob;
    };


    public void PGConnect()
    {

    UserData [] uds;
    UserData ud; // с одной структурой все работает, но мне нужен масив, я его объявил выше

        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5433;User Id=" + config.PGLogin + ";" +
           "Password=" + config.PGPass + ";Database=" + config.PGdbName + ";");

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        catch(SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

        }


        // NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT city, state FROM cities", conn);
        string commandText = @"SELECT id, guid, username, userblob FROM ""USERS"" ";

        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(commandText, conn);

        try
        {
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //ud.id = Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
                //ud.guid = (dr[1].ToString());
                //ud.name = (dr[2].ToString());
                //ud.userblob = (byte[])dr[3];
                //а в массив как?
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы распределить память под массив, надо знать его длину, а Вам она заранее неизвестна. Заполняйте список:

```
List<UserData> uds = new List<UserData>();
...
while (dr.Read())
{
  UserData ud;
  ud.id = Int32.Parse(dr[0].ToString());
  ud.guid = dr[1].ToString();
  ud.name = dr[2].ToString();
  ud.userblob = (byte[])dr[3];
  uds.Add(ud);
}
```

Если результат обязательно нужен в виде массива:

```
return uds.ToArray();
```

Comment: а чем `UserData ud`  отличается от `UserData ud = new UserData();` ?

И чем мой объявление `uds` отличается от вашего? Вроде бы компилируется и в сети примеры видел, что как я можно.

Comment: @Suliman: `UserData ud` объявляет переменную, но не инициализирует её. `new UserData` создаёт _новое_ значение (в отличие от C++, не обязательно в куче), которым можно инициализировать переменную. То же относится и к массивам (которые в C# являются ссылочными типами, то есть переменная содержит не сам массив, а лишь ссылку на него).

Comment: @VladD, а чем плоха не инициализированная переменная?

Если мне нужно чтобы функция возвращала массив структур, то как мне написать?

Comment: @Suliman - В Вашем случае со структурой, действительно, `new` можно не вызывать. .NET сам ее "закоробчит" внутри `List<>.Add`.

Comment: @Suliman: Ну, если вы инициализируете все поля вручную, то можно использовать. Но использовать неинициализированную переменную C# вам не даст. (Это даже в C++ есть undefined behaviour.)